# Building android application

Tags: android

I am trying to build a simple application with a button "Play" for Android.In the MainActivty.java file,I get errors with the following code,so what do I need to rectify here?

```
package com.example.simplemusicplayer;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
}

Button playButton=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
playButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
@Override
public void onClick(View v){
    //TODO Auto generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Starting to play",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();       
}
});
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move

```
Button playButton=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
playButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
@Override
public void onClick(View v){
    //TODO Auto generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Starting to play",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();       
}
});
```

inside `onCreate()`.

And remove the extra `}` from the end of `onCreateOptionsMenu`.

I also advise you read [Building Your First Android App](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html), which is a great guide that will teach you the basics.

Comment: Can you please explain how does this code work?And Also which onCreate() there are 3 over there.

Comment: `findViewById()` is a `non-static` method, so it can only be called from `non-static` methods. In this case, `onCreate` is one such method. Most of your code should lie within other methods. I **highly** recommend you read beginner Android tutorials or Java tutorials for a better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
package com.example.simplemusicplayer;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button playButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        playButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Starting to play",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```